# chmod command in Ubuntu works from command line but not from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I have a directory structure `/var/www/html/storage/user/job_id`. The permission of user directory is `0777` and owner is '`user@example.com`' that is a FTP user and group is '`www-data`'. I need to run a bash script on file upload to perform some tasks after files are uploaded. For that, I need to change the ownership of the directory user. **inotify** catches the new file creation events in FTP directory. On new file creation event, I call a command to change the ownership of the same directory like

```
chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html/storage/user
```

But the problem here is if I run this command directly in the terminal, it is executed successfully while it's not changing the ownership when called from a bash file. I am running the sh script from root user. The owner of this script is root and it is set to executable mode.

Comment: execute the script with bash -x to debug the output.

Comment: I get the following output: `+ chown root:www-data /var/www/html/storage/user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem frequently. Add `/` at the end, it worked for me.

```
chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html/storage/user/
```